# Why does my Macbook not find my wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, macbook

We have a Belkin router, a desktop PC connected via LAN cable, and various other devices connected via wifi. Our Macbook connected fine until upgraded to Leopard upon which it just flat out refused to connect. Nothing change on the router side and the settings in the Macbook appear the same.

Any ides on what may be the issue here?

Comment: But does it actually *see* your network?

Comment: As far as we can tell, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem a few weeks ago - it turned out that a firmware upgrade on the router allowed the Mac to see the network. I'm not too clear on the specifics of why, but that would be my first step, for sure.

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion. Unfortunately, the firmware is up-to-date. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Please add some information.

1) If you attach the MacBook using a LAN cable, everything works just fine?

2) Does your Macbook show the Belkin router network if you show networks (from the Airport icon in the menu bar)?

3) Can you connect manually?

4) What kind of security do you employ on the Belkin router? A LAN_cable connection is not bothered by WEP, WPA or MAC-address-filtering, but a WiFi connection is.

You could install Growl + HardwareGrowl (http://growl.info/extras.php) to see on Growl what your MacBook connects to.